# Pandas TypeError: Could not convert to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I am working on a project where I imported data from SQL into a pandas DataFrame. This seems to go swimmingly, but when I take the `pandas.mean()` it throws a TypeError saying that a concatenated list of the values cannot be converted to numeric (see below):

Example Dataframe:

```
  ProductSKU OverallHeight
0   AAI2185           74.5
1   AAI2275             47
2   AAI2686           56.5
3  AASA1002          73.23
```

Function Call:

```py
avgValue = df["OverallHeight"].dropna().mean()             <--- Breaks here
```

Console Output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5310, in stat_func
    numeric_only=numeric_only)

  ... 

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 293, in nanmean
    the_sum = _ensure_numeric(values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum))

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 743, in _ensure_numeric
    raise TypeError('Could not convert %s to numeric' % str(x))

TypeError: Could not convert 74.54756.573.23 to numeric
```

The strangest thing is that it works perfectly fine when I import the same data through a CSV. It only breaks when I load it through SQL, could there be something I did incorrectly there?

Comment: Can you put a a code that reproduce the error ? Your code is working...ouput {'Average': 61.763999999999996,
 'LowerBound': 16.28734181143033,
 'MissingData': 0,
 'OutsideRange': 0,
 'StDev': 15.158886062856554,
 'UpperBound': 107.24065818856965}

Comment: Check `df['OverallHeight-ToptoBottom'].dtype`.  I suspect that column contains strings (which might show up as type `object`), not floating point values.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - Bingo. You hit the nail on the head with the dtype. I fixed it using pd.to_numeric() to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

If you got a similar TypeError after a groupby operation (e.g. `TypeError: Could not convert ace to numeric`), then you probably have pandas>=2.0.

`groupby.mean()` has `numeric_only=` argument whose default value was True in the past but since pandas 2.0, its default value is False. An implication is that string columns are not dropped when a statistical method such as `mean` or `std` is called on the groupby object (as was done in the past). To solve the issue, pass `numeric_only=True`.

An example that shows the problem and the solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Grouper": ["A", "B", "A", "B", "A"],
    "Name": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    "Value": [0.95, 0.25, 0.25, 0.10, 1.00]
})

grouped = df.groupby("Grouper").mean()                    # <---- TypeError: Could not convert ace to numeric

grouped = df.groupby("Grouper").mean(numeric_only=True)   # <---- OK
```

Comment: This solution is Ok. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As the console output reveals, there's a problem with the dataframe column `'OverallHeight-ToptoBottom'`.

My guess, as @Warren Weckesser [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522741/pandas-mean-typeerror-could-not-convert-to-numeric#comment76038073_44522741), is that the columns contains strings. In order to check the data types of that column run

```
print(df['OverallHeight-ToptoBottom'].dtype)
```

Assuming that the above is true, converting the column data type to float should solve the problem. For that use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

```
df["OverallHeight-ToptoBottom"] = pd.to_numeric(df["OverallHeight-ToptoBottom"], downcast="float")
```

Answer (score -1):

This will helps to convert obj to float type.

df['column_name'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column_name'], errors='coerce')

Comment: This answer is incomplete, as it does not explain how `coerce` is helping, nor to what extent it complements the already-acepted anwser.

Answer (score -2):

Chances are ToptoBottom's contents are being read as a string. If you are opening a file with pythons read mode, and splitting the string based on new lines and commas the numbers are converted to string, this is why panda cant read the data or use it as a mean. Thus you get the error:

```
TypeError: Could not convert 74.54756.573.23 to numeric
```

to remove the conversion issue, you want to convert it to numeric values, you can use pandas to_numeric() function