# Pandas dataframe group by column and apply min, max, average on different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking a way to transform this dataframe below

```
itemid  clock   value_min   value_avg   value_max   item_type
A1  27/05/2021    4             7           38          cpu
A2  27/05/2021    4             5           15          mem
B1  27/05/2021    1             2           5           cpu
B2  27/05/2021    3             20          86          mem
A1  28/05/2021    8             8           9           cpu
A2  28/05/2021    1             2           5           mem
B1  28/05/2021    0             1           2           cpu
B2  28/05/2021    4             7           8           mem
```

to

```
itemid  value_min   value_avg   value_max   item_type
A1       4           7,5          38           cpu
A2       1           3,5          15           mem
B1       0           0,5           5           cpu
B2       3           3,5          86           mem
```

I want to group by itemid and then apply the rules

- where column value_min is the min,
- where column value_avg is the mean
- where column value_max is the max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should answer your question:

```
df = df.groupby('itemid').agg({'value_min': 'min', 'value_avg': 'mean', 'value_max': 'max', 'item_type': 'first'})
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your quick answer, I am facing another issue for another set of data `issue: {TypeError}Could not convert 7.3956136117346938.066984781707598 to numeric.` Need to asking another thread

Comment: make sure to mark the most correct answer :)

Comment: that's because the its not a number, it contains two dots, therefore it cant be parsed to floating point number, its a faulty value from the provider

Comment: Ok I got it fix with pd.to_numeric thanks to [this]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522741/pandas-mean-typeerror-could-not-convert-to-numeric