# TypeError: Could not convert group to numeric

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I am going through Krish Naik's "End To End ML Project With Deployment" course on YouTube. Right now, I am in Tutorial 3. Here is [the link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqqGdu1P2FM&list=PLZoTAELRMXVPS-dOaVbAux22vzqdgoGhG&index=4).

I am facing an issue with BIVARIATE ANALYSIS ( Is gender has any impact on student's performance ? ) while performing Exploratory Data Analysis. Here is [the link to the file on GitHub](https://github.com/krishnaik06/mlproject/blob/main/notebook/1%20.%20EDA%20STUDENT%20PERFORMANCE%20.ipynb).

[image]

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Could not convert group to numeric
```

[image]
How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas TypeError: Could not convert to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522741/pandas-typeerror-could-not-convert-to-numeric)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? --

df.groupby('gender')['average'].mean()